# Как запустить проект вне среды разработки?

Tags: java, проект

Как готовый java-проект сделать независимым от среды разработки? (в моём случае это intelliJ IDEA) Опишите, пожалуйста, примерный порядок действий.

Comment: Легко. С чем именно у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: Наверное, со всем.

Comment: Может, подскажите какую-нибудь статью?

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: Удалите файлы созданные IDE

Comment: Ваш проект независим от IDE. Можете использовать его где хотите и как хотите. Если при этом возникнут проблемы, то Вы сможете задать более конкретный вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно скомпилировать проект и экспортировать в jar.
Затем можно, например,  запустить jar из командной строки (если в проекте есть метод `main`)

```
java -jar program.jar
```

или развернуть на сервере приложений (`Glassfish`, `Wildfly`).

Все зависит от специфики вашего проекта.